# why is my input fields not showing in the website?

Tags: django, django-crispy-forms

I have created a login and registration page using the same code. The registration page shows username input fields and other fields but the login page only shows the button. Can anyone help me in this

Code:

Login Page:

```
<div class="content-section">
            <form method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <fieldset class="form-group">
                <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">Join Today</legend>
                {{ form|crispy }}
            </fieldset>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Sign Up</button>
            </div>
        </form>
        <div class="border-top pt-3">
            <small class="text-muted">
                Already Have An Account? <a class="ml-2" href="{% url 'login' %}">Sign In</a>
            </small>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Registration Page:

```
<div class="site-section">
            <form method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <fieldset class="form-group">
                <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">Log In </legend>
                {{ form|crispy }}
            </fieldset>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Login</button>
            </div>
        </form>
        <div class="border-top pt-3">
            <small class="text-muted">
                Need An Account? <a class="ml-2" href="{% url 'register' %}">Sign Up Now</a>
            </small>
        </div>
</div>
```

[Registration page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3vb6y.jpg)

[Login page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7y2MG.jpg)

This is the views of the project
Views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib import messages
from .forms import UserRegisterForm
from .models import Post
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

def home(request):
    context = {
        'posts': Post.objects.all()
    }
    return render(request, 'blog/home.html', context)


def about(request):
    return render(request, 'blog/about.html', {'title': 'About'})

def gallery(request):
    return render(request, 'blog/gallery.html', {'title': 'Gallery'})

def foodopedia(request):
    return render(request, 'blog/foodopedia.html', {'title': 'Foodopedia'})


def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserRegisterForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            messages.success(request, f'Account created for {username}!')
            return redirect('blog-home')
    else:
        form = UserRegisterForm()
    return render(request, 'blog/register.html', {'form': form})

def login(request):
    return render(request, 'blog/login.html', {'title': 'Login'})

@login_required
def profile(request):
    return render(request, 'blog/profile.html', {'title': 'Profile'})

def upload(request):
    context = {}
    if request.method == 'POST':
        uploaded_file = request.FILES['document']
        fs = FileSystemStorage()
        name = fs.save(uploaded_file.name, uploaded_file)
        context['url'] = fs.url(name)
        context['filename'] = name
        pred, probability = process_image(name)

        context['prediction'] = pred
        context['probability'] = probability

    return render(request, 'blog/foodopedia.html', context)
```

This is the urls.py of the project

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from blog import views as blog_views

from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from blog import views as blog_views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('register/', blog_views.register, name='register'),
    path('profile/', blog_views.profile, name='profile'),
    path('', include('blog.urls')),
    path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='blog/login.html'), name='login'),
    path('logout/', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(template_name='blog/logout.html'), name='logout'),

]
```

This is the form.py file:

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm


class UserRegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2']
```

Comment: I think we'd need to see some of the view code. I'm *guessing* that your Login view isn't passing a `form` to the template.

Comment: I have added the views and urls.py code.can you please help me solve the problem?

Comment: can you also provide the forms.py file?

Comment: I have added the code to forms

Comment: You don't have a login form. You need to add one, and reference it in the view, like you do with the register form.

Comment: Do i have to make that in form.py?

Comment: Create a login form and enhance your login view. Also please, double check that the Strings in the html page are correct, they seems wrong. for example Need An Account? is in your registration page html, it should be in the login one

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to create a new form in forms.py, then also dont forget to enhance your login view.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using this, adapted from the example in [this tutorial](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2020/02/django-highlights-user-models-authentication/):

```py
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm

def login(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('/')
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('/')
        else:
            form = AuthenticationForm(request.POST)
            return render(request, 'blog/login.html', {'form': form, 'title': 'Login'})
    else:
        form = AuthenticationForm()
        return render(request, 'blog/login.html', {'form': form, 'title': 'Login'})
```

To use that you would have to change the login line in your `urls.py` to this:

```py
    path('login/', blog_views.login, name='login'),
```

Comment: Oh, hang on - I've just seen your `urls.py` and you're using the default `LoginView`. In which case you don't need a `login` view in your `views.py`.

Comment: And so I think it should work, as you have it. I'd install django-debug-toolbar which will let you check what is being sent to your template in the context. You can then check whether the `form` object is being sent to the template.

Comment: I tried the alternative code which made the input field appear but gives "TypeError at /login/
login() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given " error while logging in

Comment: I’d just try following a tutorial like this https://learndjango.com/tutorials/django-login-and-logout-tutorial

Comment: Thankyou i will follow the tutorial